# Is it bad practice to shadow variables of a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Take the asynchronous Node function `fs.stat()` for an example. If I need to use `fs.stat()` on a file, then do it again later, the result is shadowed.

```
fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
  fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
  });
});
```

The `err` variable, as well as `stats` variable is shadowed - does this even matter if I won't be using the first callback inside the second? Is it better practice to rename the second callback variables?

Does overwriting these variables, once, or multiple times have any performance impact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matter of opinion, but I'd say yes - bad practice. In any case, there are two problems here

- It can be confusing for the next person (which could be you) who needs to work on this code.
- At some future time, you may need to access the outer values to provide some new functionalities (for example, want to make sure the two file objects have the same type?).  Making that change will require an annoying and error-prone edit of the entire code block.

Use different names now to prevent problems later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is bad practice. Depends on a developer viewing it of how bad it can get. If I got something like this, the first thing to pop in my mind would be

Why is he passing the `err` and `stats` to this callback?

```
fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
                        \\    \\
                         \\    \\
  fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
  });
});
```

When working in multiple instances of same function like you are doing right now. You have to make sure that all the variables can be accessed independently.

Unless you are sure one variable or construct is no longer is use, then you can re use that. But you have to mention this in a helpful comment to ensure another developer understands it.

---

**Update:**

Those variables on the callback functions have a scope limit, so they will not affect outside the function declaration.

An example of a valid case is:

```
  fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {

  });

  //Another similar functions somewhere with same varialbes
  fs.stat(file2, function(err, stats) {
  });
```

Comment: @hexacyanide Those variables in the callback have a scope limit. So, outside them will not get affected, the problem happens inside them.